# Image layer obscured by image bounds

Tags: openlayers

I have developed an application that returns an image encoded in a data url to the user, which I display on a map using `OpenLayers.Layer.Image`. I'm not sure this detail matters, but the user defines a polygon using `OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature` with the handler `OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon`. The image is added with:

```
resultLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Image(
    'Spatial result',
    resp.result.image.data,
    new OpenLayers.Bounds(resp.result.image.bounds),
    new OpenLayers.Size(resp.result.image.size.w, resp.result.image.size.h),
    {
        isBaseLayer: false,
        displayInLayerSwitcher: false,
        projection: new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913')
    }
)
```

The first time (after they've selected the control) the a user submits a polygon, the effect is spot on - the image is rendered and looks as it should as per the following image:

[image: desired result image]

When they send a second request, The result is not so pretty, as the image is obscured by something that is probably a representation of the bounding box as is shown in the following image:

[image: obscured image example]

Is there anyway to avoid this?